# Reconstruct matrix from adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to determine the entries of a matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ knowing only its eigenvalues and some (but not all) entries of the adjoint $A^{\mbox{adj}}$? In particular how many entries of $A^{\mbox{adj}}$ one must know in order to be able to "reconstruct" $A$?

As an example: determine $A\in M_2(\mathbb R)$ given its eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = -3$ and $\lambda_2 = 1$ and knowing that
$$
A^{\mbox{adj}} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -4 \\
a & b
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
In this case it is possible to reconstruct $A$ (i.e. determine $a$ and $b$) using $\det(A)$ and $\mbox{tr}(A)$.

I suspect that in general one should need to know at least $N^2-N$ elements of the adjoint.

Comment: Inevitably, you will end up with a set of linear equations. You can get a unique solution if and only if there are as many equations as there are unknowns. I suppose you will need to have, as you say, at least $N^2-N$ values known so that the number of equations drops down to less than or equal to $N$. Then the usual formula, which is $A \cdot A^{\text{adj}} = (\det A) I$ will give you the equations in the unknowns, which you can solve in order to reconstruct $A$. There are ways of approximating $A$ given it is a sparse matrix, but you want the entries exactly, so this is then possible.

Comment: Thanks. Which are the methods to approximate $A$ if it is sparse?

Comment: I'm not entirely aware, unfortunately, because I never studied sparse matrices. However, my teacher told me that they do it using something called "SVD", where there are quantities called singular values that determine the values of entries of sparse matrices in a certain range. Forgive me, because I'm not an authority on this, and don't know enough,but I'll get back if I get to know anything.

Comment: Sure. Besides I liked your question, so I have up voted it.